# Detect when user has switched editing modes in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

In CKEditor, is there an event that can be bound to which fires when the user switches between the WYSIWYG view and the source view?

If not, I need to enable/disable some other controls on the page when the view changes; what's my best strategy?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm still unable to find any documentation, but after poking around the internals of a CKEditor instance, I was able to find the event I'm looking for:

`instance.on('mode', function() {
     // Code to execute when the user switches editing modes
}`

Easy enough.  The event fires once when the editor is initialized and again any time the `source` command is activated (either through `instance.execCommand(...)` or the user clicking a `Source` toolbar button).

Comment: Thanks! I'll add that you can find which mode you're in by checking the callback argument: e.sender.mode = 'source' or 'wysiwyg'.

Answer (score 0):

I have an older version and solved this with

```
CKEDITOR.instances['terms_and_conditions'].on('mode', function() {
    console.log(this.mode); // outputs: source, wysiwyg
});
```